# BrowserRouter react-router-dom not showing components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use BrowserRouter to make a fixed NavBar with page content changing when you go in another page.
This is my `App.js`:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage/Homepage';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Preferences from './components/Preferences/Preferences';
import { Navbar, NavLink, NavMenu, NavTitle } from './components/Nav/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar>
          <NavMenu>
            <NavTitle>Application</NavTitle>
            <NavLink to={'/dashboard'}>
              Dashboard
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to={'/preferences'}>
              Preferences
            </NavLink>
          </NavMenu>
        </Navbar>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact element={Homepage} />
            <Route path='/dashboard' element={Dashboard} />
            <Route path='/preferences' element={Preferences} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

This is `Dashboard.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("Dashboard")
  };

  render() {
    return(
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    )
  };
}
```

The others page component are the same as this one.

The NavBar is shown, but not the content when I change path.

I tried to search online but seems nobody had my problem, so I'm wrong something.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575675/react-error-no-routes-matched-location-after-ive-tried-solutions-in-other/74575716#74575716

Answer (score 0):

use Switch instead of routers

```
      <Switch>
         <Route path='/' exact element={Homepage} />
         <Route path='/dashboard' element={Dashboard} />
         <Route path='/preferences' element={Preferences} />
      </Switch>
```

Comment: Switch was not found in my react-router-dom, I searched online and I found to swap it with Routes. Should I try to install an older version of the library to try Switch or I missing something else?